# Remap Esc to Caps Lock after mapping Caps Lock to Ctrl and Esc with xcape

Tags: keyboard-layout, capslock, xcape

I currently have <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> mapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> when held and <kbd>Esc</kbd> when tapped (for vim) via these commands in `.xinitrc`

```
setxkbmap -option 'caps:ctrl_modifier'
xcape -e 'Caps_Lock=Escape'
```

This works, but leaves me without <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> so I want to remap <kbd>Esc</kbd> to <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>.
I've tried setting it with `xmodmap -e 'keycode 9 = Caps_Lock'` but that overrides the mapping on the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key as well.
Is there any way to achieve these mappings?

```
Caps Lock -> Ctrl and Esc
Esc -> Caps Lock
```

Comment: @Fox Took me a while to understand what you meant. `setxkbmap -option 'caps:swapescape' -option 'caps:ctrl_modifier'; xmodmap -e 'keycode 255 = Escape'; xcape -e '#66=Escape'` works. 66 is the code for caps on my keyboard. `Caps_Lock=Escape` can't be used because the `setxkbmap` already gave Esc the Caps_Lock keysym (if I understand correctly). Post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setxkbmap` or `xmodmap` to swap Caps Lock and Escape.  With `xmodmap` you could have:

```
! Remove Caps_Lock modifier from real Caps Lock key
clear Lock
! Set real Caps Lock key to present as (left) control
keycode 66 = Control_L
! Set real Escape key to present as Caps Lock
keycode 9 = Caps_Lock
! Make a fake key to hold the Escape keysym, so xcape can use it
keycode 255 = Escape
! Make Caps_Lock and Control_L work as one would expect
add Lock = Caps_Lock
add Control = Control_L
```

(The lines starting with `!` are comments.)

Put this in `~/.xmodmaprc` and run `xmodmap ~/.xmodmaprc`,
then run `xcape -e '#66=Escape'` to add Escape functionality to the real Caps Lock key.